# MDBottomNavigation transition direction

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Is there a way to change the transition direction on a MDBottomNavigation?
I can't figure out how...

```
bottom_navigation.transition.direction = 'left'
```

is not working - i get the error

```
 AttributeError: 'MDBottomNavigation' object has no attribute 'transition'
```

Comment: Try `bottom_navigation.ids.tab_manager.transition.direction = 'left'`.